# How to unlock an LG mp260?

Tags: rooting, lg, sim-unlocking

How do I unlock and root an LG MP260? My LG v30 was stolen and I am trying to use an older phone from Metro PCS on my T-Mobile account until I can replace it.

Answer (score 0):

When I moved my phone from MetroPCS to T-Mobile, I did not need to unlock it. Since MetroPCS is now a T-Mobile brand, it should be easy.